# For my object the fields are null although I check this with *ngIf

Tags: angular, forms, angular-material, formgroups

I have the problem that my form fields in Angular. For my object (CreatePayment)  the fields are null although I check this with `*ngIf`. I use the Angular version 14

**payment-model-dialog.component**

```
export class PaymentModalDialogComponent implements OnInit {

  public createPaymentForm: FormGroup;
  public readonly destroySubject = new Subject<void>();

  constructor(
    private paymentService: PaymentService,
    public modalRef: MatDialogRef<PaymentModalDialogComponent>
  ) {
    this.createPaymentForm = new FormGroup({
      title: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
      description: new FormControl(''),
    });
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {

  }

  public createPayment(): void {

    const payment: CreatePayment = {
      title: this.createPaymentForm.get('title').value,
      description: this.createPaymentForm.get('description').value,
    }

    this.paymentService.createPayment(payment);
  }
}
```

**payment-modal-dialog.component.html**

```html
<form [formGroup]="createPaymentForm">
  <mat-form-field>
    <mat-label
            for="payment-titel">Titel</mat-label>
    <input matInput id="payment-titel" formControlName="title"/>
    <mat-error
      *ngIf="createPaymentForm.controls['title'].invalid &&
      createPaymentForm.controls['titel'].touched">
      <label *ngIf="createPaymentForm.controls['titel'].hasError('required')">Dies ist ein Pflichtfeld.</label>
    </mat-error>
  </mat-form-field>
  <mat-form-field>
    <mat-label
            for="payment-description">Beschreibung</mat-label>
    <input matInput id="payment-description" formControlName="description"/>
    <mat-error
      *ngIf="createPaymentForm.controls['description'].invalid &&
      createPaymentForm.controls['description'].touched">
      <label *ngIf="createPaymentForm.controls['description'].hasError('required')">Dies ist ein Pflichtfeld.</label>
    </mat-error>
  </mat-form-field>

</form>
```

Error Message

```bash
error TS2531: Object is possibly 'null'. title: this.createPaymentForm.get('title').value,

error TS2531: Object is possibly 'null'. description: this.createPaymentForm.get('description').value,
```

This error message should not come up because I query the field with `*ngIf`.

I hope you can help me? Many thanks :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It needs checking in the code and not in the HTML.
You can do the checking by if statement or simply use question marks "Non-null assertion operator" like:

```
title: this.createPaymentForm?.get('title')?.value,
description: this.createPaymentForm?.get('description')?.value,
```

Here you can find a good guide to the Non-null assertion operator:
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html